# How do a plot the surface given by e^-(y)*cos(x) in scilab?

Tags: plot, graph, 3d, surface, scilab

I want to plot a 3d surface in scilab with this profile: e^(-y)*cos(x). I plotted in geogebra and it gone allright, but when I try it in scilab it returns another surface that does not correspond to the geogebra plot

I was trying to plot this surface in scilab to get something like that:

[geogebra plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPGY2.png)

But, instead, what i get is this:

[scilab plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ8no.png)

my code is:

x=[-10:0.1:10];
y = [-10:0.1:10];

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y)

Z = (%e^(-Y)).*cos(X)

surf(X,Y,Z, 'facecol','blue','edgecol','black')

Answer (score 0):

You should use exp(-Y) instead of %e^(-Y) because %e^(-Y) computes the matricial exponent instead of elementwise exponent.